# AWS Amazon Linux: how to upload files from local to /var/www/html?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am very new to `Linux`, just got `Putty` set up and connected to my `Amazon Linux` instance; followed the WordPress uploading tutorial but couldn't see the `WordPress` homepage (returning 500 error, previously returned `Apache` homepage at the same address).

Now obviously, i need to look further to upload my local website to `/var/www/html`. Wondering what is the standard way to do this? I have had experience in uploading files to `cPanel` via `Filezilla` but how about this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pscp command if you are using windows. 
See: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html and http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Install a FTP server like  vsftpd

```
sudo yum install vsftpd
```

Then open the port 20 and 21 in ec2 firewall.

Configure your ftp server with the server elastic IP address

Create a FTP user and then you can configure your filezila to connect with this instance